# select the first and last rows of subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which can be generated by the following code:

```
dt=data.frame(Time=seq.Date(from =as.Date("2000/1/31"),by="month",length.out = 70),
          ID=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)),
          Category=rep(c("Satisfactory","Marginal","Satisfactory","Marginal","Satisfactory")))
dt=dt[with(dt,order(ID)),]
dt
```

I would like to find out the time period when ID belongs to a category. The desired result will look like this:

```
           Time    ID     Category
1  2000-01-31     1 Satisfactory
2  2001-03-31     1 Satisfactory
3  2001-10-31     1     Marginal
4  2002-05-31     1     Marginal
5  2002-12-31     1 Satisfactory
6  2004-03-02     1 Satisfactory
7  2004-10-01     1     Marginal
8  2005-05-01     1     Marginal
9  2000-03-02     2     Marginal
10 2000-10-01     2     Marginal
```

It will be ideal if the code is in `dplyr`.

Comment: Please provide an example that is easy to copy&paste and your current effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by run-length id of 'Category' (`rleid(Category)`), we get the row index of the first and last elements, extract that column (`$V1`) and subset the dataset.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[c(1, .N)] , by = rleid(Category)]$V1
df1[i1]
#         Time ID       Category
# 1: 30/06/2014  1   Satisfactory
# 2: 31/10/2014  1   Satisfactory
# 3: 30/11/2014  1 Unsatisfactory
# 4: 31/05/2015  1 Unsatisfactory
# 5: 30/06/2015  1       Marginal
# 6: 31/08/2015  1       Marginal
# 7: 30/09/2015  1   Satisfactory
# 8: 30/11/2015  1   Satisfactory
# 9: 30/06/2013  2       Marginal
#10: 31/05/2014  2       Marginal
```

---

Or another option with `base R` is using `ave` to create a logical index and then use that to subset the dataset

```
 df1[with(df1, as.logical(ave(seq_along(Category),
   cumsum(c(TRUE,Category[-1]!=Category[-nrow(df1)])), 
    FUN = function(x) x %in% c(head(x,1), tail(x,1))) )),]
#         Time ID       Category
#1  30/06/2014  1   Satisfactory
#5  31/10/2014  1   Satisfactory
#6  30/11/2014  1 Unsatisfactory
#12 31/05/2015  1 Unsatisfactory
#13 30/06/2015  1       Marginal
#15 31/08/2015  1       Marginal
#16 30/09/2015  1   Satisfactory
#18 30/11/2015  1   Satisfactory
#19 30/06/2013  2       Marginal
#23 31/05/2014  2       Marginal
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(gr = cumsum(dplyr::lag(Category,
         default = Category[1L])!= Category)) %>% 
    slice(c(1, n())) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-gr)    
#         Time    ID       Category
#        (chr) (int)          (chr)
#1  30/06/2014     1   Satisfactory
#2  31/10/2014     1   Satisfactory
#3  30/11/2014     1 Unsatisfactory
#4  31/05/2015     1 Unsatisfactory
#5  30/06/2015     1       Marginal
#6  31/08/2015     1       Marginal
#7  30/09/2015     1   Satisfactory
#8  30/11/2015     1   Satisfactory
#9  30/06/2013     2       Marginal
#10 31/05/2014     2       Marginal
```

Comment: You should point out that OP would need a `library(data.table)` for this solution.

Comment: Please add `by = ` to your answers, otherwise it is impossible to understand the code for someone who isn't familiar with `data.table`

Comment: Thanks, my connection got reset while adding the answer.  Corrected the post

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution if you want to use the `dplyr` logic (even if the `rleid` function from `data.table` is still required)

```
library(data.table); library(dplyr)
Data %>% mutate(groupCat = rleid(Category),groupID = rleid(ID)) %>%
group_by(groupCat,groupID) %>% filter(row_number()==1 |row_number()==n() ) %>%
ungroup() %>% select(-starts_with("group"))
```

Comment: Hi @adiana, I have found one issue with your code. I think the data should be `rleid` function should refer to both Category and ID. Otherwise the result won't pick up ID's in sequence with the same category. Anyway to accommodate this?

Answer (score 0):

a base solution :

```
aggregate(df$Time,FUN=min,by=list(df$ID,df$Category))
```

can be used as a filter.

and the same for max:

```
aggregate(df$Time,FUN=max,by=list(df$ID,df$Category))
```

so

```
rbind(aggregate(df$Time,FUN=min,by=list(df$ID,df$Category)),
      aggregate(df$Time,FUN=max,by=list(df$ID,df$Category)))
```

will give you:

```
  Group.1        Group.2          x
1       1       Marginal 2015-06-30
2       2       Marginal 2013-06-30
3       1   Satisfactory 2014-06-30
4       1 Unsatisfactory 2014-11-30
5       1       Marginal 2015-08-31
6       2       Marginal 2014-05-31
7       1   Satisfactory 2015-11-30
8       1 Unsatisfactory 2015-05-31
```

you can change names etc. I hope I got you right.
is there a chance you want the by to include the year? I can see this from

```
30/06/2014  1   Satisfactory
31/10/2014  1   Satisfactory
30/09/2015  1   Satisfactory
30/11/2015  1   Satisfactory
```

so you can add the year to the list of 'by' easy : `by=list(df$ID,df$Category,format(df$Time,'%Y'))`
or any other factor